# How much data should i encrypt with RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt?

Tags: encryption

I found an example online using RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt which encrypts andd decrypts a string. Only now did i realize, is this a bad idea? Should i be using something like RijndaelManaged and encrypting the Key and IV (48bytes) with RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt  then encrypt the rest of the data with AES?

Extra question: Would RSACryptoServiceProvider blow up in my face if i try to encrypt 1k+ or give me terrible performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using RSA in combination with Rijndael is the best solution. And there's an example on the corresponding [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx) page.

Extra answer: if you try to pass more data than provider instance allows (for default 1024-bit (128-byte) key and default PKCS#1.5 11-byte padding it's 117 bytes) CryptographicException will be thrown. If you try to use some kind of loop approach to pass data in chunks then it will give you terrible performance.